# How can I calculate the recursive calls to this function and what will be the correct answer to it?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math, recurrence

How can I calculate the recursive calls to this function and what will be the correct answer to it??????

```
int func(x,y)
{
  if (x % y == 0) return y;
  x = x % y; 
  return func(y,x);
}
```

I need a formula for it or an explanation or general expression for it really confused here?????

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: It is an improper function in `C and `C++`

Comment: 1: One "?" is enough, no need for five or six. 2: This is not valid code: `x` and `y` don't have a type, and `n` and `m` aren't even declared. 3: What do you mean by "calculate the recursive calls to this function"? and by "the correct answer to it"?

Comment: @gx_: x and y will default to being ints, though there should be a compiler warning.

Comment: @Douglas Not in Standard C++. But in C, probably (sorry, C is the past to me).

Answer (score 2):

using **global variable** is easy solution.

```
    int i;
    main()
    {

        i=0; //if you want to avoid main call just start with i=-1     
        //if you are using loop and then calling function in loop ,  
        //make i value zero or -1 to know how many recursive calls are made to particular call.  

        func(x,y);

        //now i consists number of recursive calls made.
    }

    int func(int x,int y)
    {

        i++;
        if (x % y == 0) return m;
        x = x % y; 
        return func(y,x);
    }
```

Comment: Global variables is a bad experience, in simple (single-thread) programs it is not so bad, but in multi-thread programs global data is a bad idea, unless it is protected with critical section, however it may influence the loss of performance.

Answer (score 0):

First off your code won't compile.  You need to give `x` and `y` types like `int` or `long`.  Secondly you ;probably want to order `x` and `y` before you do anything else.  Some thing like:

```
int func(int x, int y) {
    int mx = max(x, y);
    int mn = min(x, y);
    // as above with mx for x and mn for y
}
```

Comment: it was just to show the q not exactly an exact code

Comment: but you distract from your point by needlessly omitting important details like this.

Answer (score 0):

> How do you know the  number of calls?

Well, there are two ways.

1. **Instrument the code**: add a variable that counts up to the top of the function, and when the function completes, print the count.
2. **Walk the code yourself**: Pretend to be the computer, calculate each step and follow the decision path. Do this for a variety of inputs and see what results it gives you. Count the number of steps it takes. Do remember to take into account where you are returning to - recursive functions return back to itself.

> How to find the correct answer?

Similar to above.

1. Run the code and print the result.
2. Walk through the code, and figure out what the result is for each step, and what the final result is.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your function into this:

```
int func(int x, int y, int& n)//I asume x and y are ints
{
  if (x % y == 0) return y;
  x = x % y; 
  return func(y,x, n+1);//not sure if I understood question correctly, so I think you need to change n value here.
}

int func(int x, int y, int& n)//I asume x and y are ints
{
    ++n;//not sure if I understood question correctly, it may be you need this place for count variable increment
    if (x % y == 0) return y;
    x = x % y; 
    return func(y,x, n);
}
```

And to use that function you will need:

```
int x = 1000, y = 7, n = 0;
int ret = func(x, y, n);  //n must be zero
```

BTW, also you can use global variables, however it is not the best experience, so better pass one more parameter to the function.